# Square root and Cubic root of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

Need

- an example of a matrix with a square root but it does not admit any cubic roots
- an example of a matrix with a cubic root but it does not admit any square root

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: For the second question, assuming these are matrices over $\mathbb R$, how about $[-1]$? :)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   yeah ! i try to find a matrix that its determinant is negative so it d'ont admit a squar root in R, i found one,  or nilpotent matrix

Comment: Are we talking about matrices with real entries only, or can our square and cube roots have complex entries?

Comment: @Lynn     yeah ! i also made that exemple thank you ! ^^

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Any matrix, its can be with real and complex entries

Comment: Then $-1$ doesn't work as a counterexample, since $i$ is a square root of $-1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes! but in R its work

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can find suitable examples among the powers of [Jordan blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) for $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: if we associate a matrix of jordan 2,2, it is nilpotent of order 2, so it does not admit any root ...

Comment: You are correct in observing that the $2 \times 2$ matrix 
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
does not admit an $n$th root for any $n \geq 2$.  To answer your question, however, you must consider larger blocks.  I know that the first condition is fulfilled by a $3 \times 3$ matrix, and the second is fulfilled by a $5 \times 5$ matrix; I haven't been able to come up with smaller examples.

Comment: But how i can proov that its does not admit squar or cubic root please  , i didn't understand , thank u

Comment: @Marwa if a $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ is nilpotent, then by the Cayley Hamilton theorem it must satisfy $M^2=0$. Any square root of $J$ would necessarily be nilpotent.

Answer (score -1):

COMMENT.- The cube of $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{pmatrix}$ is equal to
$B=\begin{pmatrix}468&576&684\\1062&1305&1548\\1656&2034&2412\end{pmatrix}$ so it is evident that $B$ has a cubic root equal to $A$.

In order to know if $B$ has a square root we must to find a matrix $X=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}$ such that its square, i.e $X^2=\begin{pmatrix}a^2+bd+cg&ab+be+ch&ac+bf+ci\\da+ed+fg&bd+e^2+fh&dc+ef+fi\\ga+hd+ig&gb+he+ih&cg+fh+i^2\end{pmatrix}$ be equal to the matrix $B$. This means that we must solve a system of nine equations with nine unknowns to have a non-simple example with $0$ and $1$ convenient to facilitate the task that is guessed laborious.

But above all this should serve to take into account two important things: that it is necessary to indicate to which set the terms of the matrix belong and mainly note that not all matrices have cubic or square roots for the simple reason that the system that we must solving in general will not be compatible.In the language of functional analysis it is said that a function $f$ "operates" in an algebra $A$ if $f(a)$ makes sense for all elements $a$ of $A$. Thus, and using this language we could say that neither the square root function nor the cubic root function "operate" on the algebra of the square matrices of order $n$ (instead the exponential function $f (x) = e^x$ does operate in this algebra).